# Is Python programming for Logitech G15 possible?

Tags: python, logitech, g15

I have a Logitech G15 keyboard. It has a screen. Can i program this? I googled it but the one site i found didn't work.. It seems like it is possible, but i cannot grasp how.

Thanks!
This site is truly great.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the G15 comes with an SDK. You could use that along with the `ctypes` module to call into the supplied DLLs. Otherwise, I imagine you'd have to use something like Swig or Boost.Python to make a Python module for the G15 from the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be programmable even with bash shell: http://www.g15-applets.de/tux---benutzername---zeit---datum---cpu---ram-t4336.html
so it should be easy to program this keyboard in python as well.

Of course you have to install "g15composer" first, which should be available under ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install g15composer
```